# How can I show the total for a purchase order?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that is updated with different purchase orders in it.

I basically need to show the to show the total for each individual purchase order.

For example I have order 10,11,12 etc with different amounts entered.

The only problem is that the orders come in different orders.

I need a formula that will total the different purchase orders even tho they come in a random order.

They are all in the same column however, as well as the price.

Thanks in advance.

Leigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF`

```
     A          B         C        D
1    OrderNo    Price     OrderNo  OrderTotal
2    10         25        10       =SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,"=" & C2, $B$2:$B$10) // =175
3    12         100       11       =SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,"=" & C3, $B$2:$B$10) // =100
4    10         50        12       =SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,"=" & C4, $B$2:$B$10) // =200
5    11         10
6    10         50
7    12         100
8    11         75
9    11         15
10   10         50
```

Comment: thank you for the response but I don't want to be able to hard code each individual order no, I would like the spreadsheet to get each variable if it is possible, Thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you have now resolved this. Thanks it did work had to give it time as had 30000 records to work out thanks again

Comment: congratulations for understanding the question !-)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a pivot table.  Put the Order No in the Row field and Sum of Price in the data field.

Comment: Agreed. Best approach is to use pivot table in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.  Are we talking about the parts of a purchase order being separated from one another in the spreadsheet?  I'm not sure I understand the question...

If you have an order ID or other unique field, you might be able to use VLOOKUP (but only if there's just row for each order).  You might also be able to sort by order number and use SUM.